# Как исправить блокировку главного окна приложения и осуществить правильный вывод?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, асинхронность, qthread

Прошу помочь мне.  Есть такой код (использую *PyQt4* и *Python 3.6.3*):

```
class gui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gui, self).__init__() 
        self.output = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('...')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.bar)
        ...    

    def foo(self,param):
        some_data = func(param) #некая функция, использующая param и выполняющаяся длительное время
        return some_data

    def bar(self):
        for i in range(...):
            self.output.setText(str(self.foo(i)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю кнопку, окно начинает ***`подвисать`***, а в `output` ничего не выводится, до тех пор, пока цикл не отработает.

Понимаю, что проблема в "долгой" функции `func()` (она и вешает приложение) и нужно копать в сторону многопоточности (класс `Thread`) или асинхронности (`asyncio`).

Пробовал запустить `foo()` в отдельном потоке, но результата это почему-то не дало (наверное неправильно делал). Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из вариантов:

С импортом думаю разберетесь. А лучше побыстрее переходите на PyQt5.

```
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *
#from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import time

class Worker(QObject):

    started  = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    data     = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.running = False
        self.param = 0

    @pyqtSlot()
    def read_data_from_sensor(self):
#        print(self.param)
        self.started.emit()
        time.sleep(1)                                        # Моделируем процесс блокировки
        while self.running and self.param:
            dt  = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            self.data.emit(dt)
            QThread.msleep(1000)                              # Моделируем процесс блокировки
            self.param -= 1
        self.finished.emit()


class Gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Реализация QThread-moveToThread")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


        self.label = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setText('В ожидании')
        self.label.adjustSize()

        self.output = QTextEdit()

        self.button = QPushButton('Начать', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.read_data)        

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)        
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self._worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self._worker.data.connect(self.update_label)

        self._thread = QThread(self)
        self._thread.start()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        """ slot будет вызван, когда начнется сбор данных """
        self.label.setText("Начиная читать")
        self.button.setText("Стоп")
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        """ slot будет вызван, когда сбор данных закончится """
        self.label.setText("В ожидании")
        self.button.setText("Начать")
        self.button.setEnabled(True)
        self.output.append(" finished {}".format("-"*20))
        self._worker.running = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def read_data(self):
        """ Начать / остановить чтение при нажатии кнопки """
#        print("_worker.running:", self._worker.running)

        if self._worker.running:
            self._worker.running = False
        else:
            self._worker.running = True
            self._worker.param   = 10
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self._worker.read_data_from_sensor)
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_label(self, data):
        """ Slot будет вызываться при появлении новых данных """
        self.label.setText(data)
        self.output.append(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! А Вы случайно не знаете, как решить мою задачу, используя asyncio? Просто, мне кажется, это было бы проще (хотя Ваш код мне понятен). Я новичок в конкурентном программировании. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @user347195  посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452804/python-qt-gui-and-several-tasks